Bb Concert Pitch in Musescore
I frequently use Musescore in arranging and recently I have been needing to use it in my music classes.
It was here that my teacher told us about the concert pitch button and that I could set all my instruments into C so that they are all in the same key.
But that changes the key of trumpet, and I play trumpet in Bb so this aroused my curiosity and I’m wondering:
Is there any way to, instead of setting all instruments to C, can I set them to Bb so I’m reading everything in Bb instead of C?

Doesn't the 'concert pitch' button set all transposing instruments so they read  - therefore play - in the same key? Never used Musescore, so ignorant!

In MS3 there was View > Synthesizer > Tuning, which I believe in MS4 they've removed entirely. But you can select all notes and set the tuning to -200 cents if you really want.

I think I may have accidentally set off a minor argument... oops

@Tim Yes musescore will set all the instruments to the key of C, and I want it to set them all to Bb. Does that help?

If you include transposing instruments in your score (like Bb Trumpet) you have the choice of displaying that instrument in the full score in concert pitch or transposed.
I suppose you could display concert pitch then transpose the whole score down a tone.  But I suggest you carefully examine your reasons for wanting to do this.  It seems to have no practical purpose.

It does make some sense? The transposition of an instrument is quite arbitrary and depends on your reference system. And especially in bands and stuff Bb is more or less the “standard pitch” rather than C. So what the OP essentially wants to do is to define C in such a way that the Trumpet is non-transposing. And I think this is a very practical purpose. If you are not used to concert pitch notation, then it can be hard to wrap around to think in Bb or Eb or whatever rather then C or F. F minor become Eb minor or D♯ minor in concert pitch, which is not exactly easy to get around.

Okay, so if I understand you correctly you want to notate everything in Trumpet pitch rather than concert pitch. I do not think that there is an actual mechanism for that in MuseScore (except changing transposition for all instruments to Bb and then changing back).
You could composing everything a whole step lower and eventually transpose the entire score, but then everything will sound a whole step lower.
Else I think there is no other way than editing each staff and changing the transposition to Bb, and when you are done to change the transposition back.

But wouldn't this create an even greater problem in case there are other transposing instruments?

@musicamante What are you refering to?

If I understood the question and your answer correctly, the OP wants to use a different pitch as a "virtual concert pitch". But if the score contains instruments that also have a different transposition than Bb, wouldn't it be fundamentally wrong, and possibly even more confusing? For instance, writing in a "Bb concert pitch" would make a french horn part quite confusing, especially if it has then be transposed back in the instrument pitch.

@musicamante - And it hurts even more for French horn since a lot of (older) music for it skips key signatures completely regardless of the key of the full piece (e.g. the Pomp and Circumstance Marches).

@Dekkadeci Uh, I didn't consider that, and that also happens for percussion sometimes! Timpani parts were also often written in C throughout the score, indicating the reference key. But I suppose that in this case that would almost be a benefit, as long as score/transposition setup is done appropriately (and the piece is strictly tonal)...

@musicamante Not really. If understand OP’s intention correctly he does not want to create an edition in Concert-Bb, but he wants to compose his arrangement without having to care about transposition. In this sense the final Score created from this should of course feature correct transposition.
